# Uploading a file from AngularJS to ExpressJS 4 API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, file-upload

My AngularJS app communicates with Express via an internal API.

I'm using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) in Angular to handle the uploaded files. The uploading code looks something like this:

```
 Upload.upload({
        url: '/api/uploadCSV/',
        file: CSVfile
    }).progress(function (evt) {
        var progressPercentage = parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total);
        console.log('progress: ' + progressPercentage + '% ' + evt.config.file.name);
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('file ' + config.file.name + 'uploaded. Response: ' + data);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error status: ' + status);
    })
```

In my Express `app.js`, I set up the API like this:

```
 app.post('/api/uploadCSV/', api.uploadCSV);
```

In my actual API code I'd like to do something like:

```
 exports.uploadCSV = function(req, res){
      var csv = req.body.CSVfile; // or something similar
      // and then code to parse the CSV file and save information from it to MongoDB
 }
```

I can see a few examples on SO about how to upload a file and store it to a server, but this isn't what I want to do; I just need to send the file to my server to be read and parsed.

Is this possible with Express, and if so how do I set it up?

EDIT: Or perhaps I should be reading the file in the user's browser, parsing it into JSON with Angular and sending that JSON object to my server?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ng-file-upload`, but it looks like it uploading using `multipart/form-data`, in which case you can use a module like [`multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to handle the uploads on the Express side. From there, you can use something like [`csv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv) to handle the CSV data.